# PHPExcel row starts with 1, column with 0

Tags: phpexcel

I'm just curious why row starts with 1 and column with 0. Is there any special reason or am I missing something important? Why not just both start with 0 or 1 (consistency).

```
/**
 * Set a cell value by using numeric cell coordinates
 *
 * @param string $pColumn Numeric column coordinate of the cell (A = 0)
 * @param string $pRow Numeric row coordinate of the cell
 * @param mixed $pValue Value of the cell
 * @param bool $returnCell Return the worksheet (false, default) or
   the cell (true)
 * @return PHPExcel_Worksheet|PHPExcel_Cell 
    Depending on the last parameter being specified
 */
public function setCellValueByColumnAndRow($pColumn = 0,
                                           $pRow = 1,
                                           $pValue = null,
                                           $returnCell = false)
{
    $cell = $this->getCellByColumnAndRow($pColumn, $pRow)->setValue($pValue);
    return ($returnCell) ? $cell : $this;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is backward compatibility with earlier versions after what was originally a bad decision based on the old PEAR SEW that also had zero-based column IDs